# Does compiler add new int[] when initializing an int array in Java?

Tags: java

What is the difference between the two? Is the first one actually been converted to second ?

```
int [] ar = {1,2,3,4};
and
int [] ar = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
```

Comment: `int [] ar = new {1,2,3,4};` is a compilation error

Comment: The second form is only really useful for anonymous arrays.

Comment: @5gon12eder is it because in ar ={1,2,3} memory is already allocated for ar and no need to use new[]?

Comment: @Cgraphics No, it's just an alternative in the syntax (when initializing the array where it is declared).

Comment: I have made it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answers have already pointed out, the effects of

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

and

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

are exactly the same.

In this answer, I will only elaborate on when to use which one.

The first one is clearly less to type, so use it whenever possible.  However, it can only be used when assigning directly to a variable.  Sometimes, we want to create an array without assigning to a variable.  This is called an *anonymous array*.  In this case, we need to use the second syntax.

```
head({1, 2, 3, 4});  // error
head(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4});  // ok

return {1, 2, 3, 4};  // error
return new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};  // ok
```

The presence or absence of `new` is only linguistic.  It's not like in C++ that the array is created either on the heap or on the stack.  In Java, any non-primitive object goes to the heap.

Comment: +1 for " In Java, any non-primitive object goes to the heap."

Answer (score 2):

`int [] ar = new {1,2,3,4};` will not compile.

If you mean `int [] ar = {1,2,3,4};`, then yes - it is identical to `int [] ar = new int[]{1,2,3,4};`.

Comment: My question is then which is is preferred where?

Answer (score 2):

```
int [] ar = new {1,2,3,4};
```

will give you a compilation error, i assume you meant:

```
int [] ar = {1,2,3,4};
```

In which case, the answer is yes. That is java's shorthand on declaring an array.